# Angular swiper in ngFor: how to create navigation buttons for each cycle

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

We are using swiper in an Ionic - Angular app, we create the swiper inside an ngFor but the problem is that the navigation buttons affect ALL the sliders at the same time, how can we prevent this?

html code:

```
      <div class="c-rewards__available-slider" *ngFor="let purchasableLevel of groupedPurchasables; let i = index">
      <h2 class="c-rewards__available-slider__points">{{ purchasableLevel[0]?.getPrice()?.toLocaleString() }} Points</h2>
      <swiper [config]="rewardsConfig"  (slideChange)="onSlideChange($event)" (afterInit)="afterSwiperInit($event)">
        <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let purchasableReward of purchasableLevel">
          <div class="swiper-slide__wrapper">                
            <div class="swiper-slide__wrapper__shadow">
              <app-custom-purchasable-reward-card 
                ...
                ></app-custom-purchasable-reward-card>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </swiper>
    <!-- </div> four -->
      <!-- Adding arrows when more than 4 slides-->
      <div class="swiper-button-next" ></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-prev" ></div>
  </div>
```

Ts code:

```
  public rewardsConfig: SwiperOptions = {
slidesPerView: 2,
loop: false,
//navigation: true,
pagination: {
  clickable: true,
  renderBullet: function (index: number, className: string) {
    return `<button type="button" class="${className}" aria-current="${index === 0}" aria-label="Go to slide ${index + 1}"></button>`;
  },
},
watchSlidesVisibility: true,
a11y: {
  enabled: true,
  slideRole: 'listitem'
},
observer: true,
observeParents: true,
breakpoints: {
  1024: {
    slidesPerView: 4,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  }
}
```

};

Comment: By passing in the index in the ngFor to reference which slide.  *ngFor="let purchasableReward of purchasableLevel; let i = index;"